# Как получить сумму высоты блоков

Tags: javascript

Дамы и Господа, есть некоторое количество блоков, например `<p>`. Как мне получить сумму высоты блоков? Метод приведенный ниже в примере чего то не работает, не пойму в чем дело...

```js
var par = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

for (var i = 0; i < par.length; i++) {
  var parHeight = +par[i].getBoundingClientRect().height;
}
console.log(parHeight);
```

```css
p {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p></p><p></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас `parHeight` равен последнему, тк. вы его заново объявляете каждую итерацию.

```js
var par = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
var parHeight = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < par.length; i++) {
  parHeight += par[i].getBoundingClientRect().height;
}
console.log(parHeight);
```

```css
p {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p></p><p></p>
```

Comment: Была мысль... Даже не знаю почему не попробовал так...  Благодарю...